# Show that $f_n(x) = \frac {2x+n}{x+n}$ converges uniformly to $f(x) =1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question:

Let  b ∈ $\mathbb R$ and let $f_n(x): [-b,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R $ be defined by $f_n(x) = \frac {2x+n}{x+n}$ for all n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$. Show that ($f_n$) converges uniformly to $f$ on [-b,b] where $f(x) =1$ for all $x ∈ [-b,b]$.

The question gives the hint: Use Dini’s Theorem. Also, the first line for the rough solutions sates: "We observe that $(fn)$ is a sequence of continuous
functions on [−b, b] that converges pointwise to the function $f$"

However Dini's Theorem requires that $f_n(x)$ be continuous real valued real valued functions on [-b,b]. But if we take $x=-n$ then the denominator becomes $0 $ and thus $f_n(x)$ is not continuous.

Is there a mistake in the question or have I missed something like usual? I would also like to point out that I have copied out the question exactly.

Comment: Hint : If $n$ is big enough you can apply Dini's theorem.

Comment: For $n$ big enough, $-n \notin[-b,b]$.

Comment: In the lecture notes that have been given to me Dibi's theorem is given as:"Let $(f_n)$be a sequence of continuous real valued
functions on [a, b] and suppose that $(f_n(x))$ is a monotone sequence for each x ∈ [a, b].
If $f_n → f$ and f is a continuous real valued function on [a, b], then $f_n$  uniformly converges to $f$. " We have not been given much more detail about this. Can you explain why we can disregard the first few n?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of the proof.
First, divide the domain into two regions. $[-b,0] \cup [0,b]$.
The overlap will not be an issue.

Let's look at the first region.
We want to show that $\frac{2x+n}{x+n}\leq\frac{2x+n+1}{x+n+1}$ in this region.
Assume that $x+n > 0$ because we can always start with a sufficiently large $n$.
Then, multiply each side with $(x+n)(x+n+1)$ and we get that the necessary and sufficient condition is $x\leq0$, which is true from the definition of the first region.
Therefore, we have a monotone (increasing) function on the first region, and similarly we can prove that the function is monotone (decreasing) in the second region.
Now apply Dini's theorem in each region, and we have uniformly convergent sequence of functions to $f(x)=1$, and even if we look at both regions at the same time, uniform convergence is preserved.

Comment: Thank you but I have already been able to perform the proof if I assumed that $f_n(x)$ was continuous. But as x = -n could belong to [-b,b] discontinuity is possible. Comments have said I  can take a large n, but I don't understand this step.

Comment: What it means is that when you consider the convergence of $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, it is identical to looking at the convergence of $\{f_n\}_{n=10}^{\infty}$, or any number that you start with. That is why I mentioned that we can assume $x+n > 0$, because we can start with any large number $n$. This technique can be used for solving problems related to any limits. You can truncate the first finite part and nothing will be affected.

Comment: You may have a discontinuous (or any other non-well behaving function) for the first 10000 functions, but it will have no effect on the conclusion of convergence as long as the functions after 10000 behaves well.